# round to arbitrary divisions?

Tags: language-agnostic, math, rounding

I want to round according to arbitrary divisions, e.g. I get a number from 0 to 1 and I want to round it according to divisions into 48ths, e.g. if I get something like 5/96, i want either 2/48 or 3/48. What's a good formula to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as with rounding to decimal signs. If you have `n` 'divisions' and number `x`, do `round(x*n)/n`.
In your example, it'll be `round((5/96)*48)/48 = round(2.5)/48 = 2/48`

`round` can be replaced with `floor` or `ceil`, depending on the direction you want.

Comment: a yea i realize it soon after i posted it

Answer (score 0):

Assumes integer division, so it will round down:

```
float retVal = scaleRange(in, oldMin, oldMax, newMin, newMax) {
  return (in / ((oldMax - oldMin) / (48 - 0))) + 0;
}
```